# Temporary model instances referenced as foreign keys

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-database

Is there a way to keep a Django model instance, *which is referenced by foreign keys*, in memory without storing it to the database?

The code is part of an _*add*_ overload, but the way it is implemented now is very ugly as it is hard to keep track of the new instances, and it also produces a lot of unnecessary DB accesses.
Ideally I want to keep the new instances temporary as long as the user does not call the save() method on the returned instance.

When I uncomment the save() calls like below, the SequenceAnnotation instances are not referenced in the returned Sequence instance.

```
    def __add__(self, other: Union['Sequence', str]):
        """
        This enables you to use the + operator when dealing with Sequence objects
        :param other:
        :return:
        """
        sum_seq = Sequence()

        # concatenate the actual sequences
        sum_seq.sequence = self.sequence + other.sequence

        #sum_seq.save()
        len_self_seq = len(self.sequence)

        # annotations
        annot: SequenceAnnotation
        # copy the own anntotations
        for annot in self.annotations.all():
            new_annot = deepcopy(annot)
            new_annot.id = None  # this is crucial to actually create a new instance
            new_annot.ref_sequence = sum_seq
            #new_annot.save()


        # copy the other annotations, adjust the start and end positions
        for annot in other.annotations.all():
            new_annot = deepcopy(annot)
            new_annot.id = None  # this is crucial to actually create a new instance
            new_annot.start = len_self_seq + annot.start
            new_annot.end = len_self_seq + annot.end
            new_annot.ref_sequence = sum_seq
            #new_annot.save()

        return sum_seq
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as far as I know.

Django foreign key fields are backed by `something_id` fields; assigning `foo.something` to something that has a `None` `id` [sets the backing field to `None`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3d7ac6420c0ff23305bc50c69c419c4ed5d2a838/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py#L254-L257).

You would need to implement something similar to how forms (may) have `save_m2m()` to ensure the constellation of objects gets saved in the right order.

Comment: Hi @AKX, I'll wait a little longer just in the case somebody else has a proposal, but thanks for your answer. I'm quite surprised that there seems to be no easy solution for this use-case...I imagined some miracle code which maybe replaces the missing foreign key by some kind of pointer as long as there is no ID, but it looks like its not that easy...